# Drag and Drop File Input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to drag a file into a `div` box and do 2 things:

1. Change the color of the `div` box.
2. Fill up the `<input type="file">` element in the form with the dragged file.

Here is what I have so far in my code. I have tried dragging a file to the `div` box, but when I do, it keeps redirecting the page to display the contents of the dropped file. Please help and thank you!

```js
function processFile(file) {
  file.preventDefault();
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
  document.getElementById('fileInput').value = file;
  document.getElementById('fileForm').submit();
}
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Drag and Drop</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Drag and Drop</h1>
  <div id="box" ondrop="processFile(file)">Drop here</div>
  <br>
  <form method="post" id="fileForm" action="/submitFile">
    <input type="file" name="submission" id="fileInput">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/joezimjs/pen/yPWQbd) from Joe Zim that has the drag-and-drop functionality.

You could modify the JS to change the background color of the element as well using:

```
document.getElementById('id-of-element-to-change-color').style.backgroundColor = 'gray'
```

inside the function.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan Fries.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to set event `ondragover`
2. The parameter of `ondrop` is `event` not `file`.

```js
function processFile(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
  document.getElementById('fileInput').value = event.dataTransfer.getData('file');
  document.getElementById('fileForm').submit();
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // change your color here
}
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Drag and Drop</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Drag and Drop</h1>
  <div id="box" ondrop="processFile(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drop here</div>
  <br>
  <form method="post" id="fileForm" action="/submitFile">
    <input type="file" name="submission" id="fileInput">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Tran. This works, except for the file input part, which I think has to do with what Jan Turoň mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

First, You can not set value of input file type by javascript due to security reasons (imagine web pages that steal your PC contents without your action), so don't use input file, but some div.

However, you can read the file that was dropped. The drag/drop event object, [DragEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent) interface, has a e.dataTransfer property, which you can feed to [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and then [send it via AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

Having the mentioned reference at hand, you can follow this [step by step tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/). The CSS part in your example is OK. Good luck.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you, @Jan Turoň.